# Can a function ever be on the left side of an assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c, function, syntax

I don't know what use case it might be. I was just wondering if a function would ever appear on the left side of the assignment in C/C++. Just as an example, of course it is wrong, `swap(x,y) = 100;`

Comment: You should ask for C and C++ separately.

Comment: It may look like a function, but it really a reference in C++:
`a[x] = 1;` , that is the  `operator[](int);` function

Comment: Yes it can in C++ if the functions returns a modifiable lvalue reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you can do that using references. In C++, that is, there are no references in C.

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 0;

int& swap(int x, int y) {
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    swap(x, y) = 100;
    std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 6.5.16 2 says:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

An lvalue is an expression that may designate an object (such as a name of an object or an `*p` expression where `*` is applied to a pointer to an object`). In C, function-call expressions are not lvalues.

Comment: The closest you can get is a function that returns a pointer, then de-reference the pointer:  `*getAddr(x,y) = 100;`

Comment: @abelenky: What is your metric for close? I would argue that a macro would be closer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can do this in C++ if the function returns a reference, as a reference is an lvalue.

You can't assign *directly* to the return value of a function in C since it is not an lvalue.  However if the function returns a pointer you can dereference it.  That will give you a lvalue and *then* you can assign to it.

```
int x;

int *getx()
{
    return &x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("x=%d\n", x);    // prints 0
    *getx() = 4;
    printf("x=%d\n", x);    // prints 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C language assignment expression **the left operand must design an object** into which will be stored the right operand. This means that whichever *conditional-expression* that resolves to an assignable object will do.

But because **in C doesn't exist the concept of reference object**, you **can't directly use a function on the left side of an assignment**. It is instead possible in C++ where it exist. I.e. in C++ you can have:

```
int &obj(int pos);
...
obj(0) = 3;
```

In C you can simulate the previous behavior with a little trick: make your function return a pointer to the object and then dereferencing the return value before to assign it. Consider the following fragment:

```
int *GetPtr(int pos);
...
*GetPtr(0) = 3;
```

Here the function `GetPtr()` return a reference to an object that we dereference and assign.

Comment: In C, a macro with arguments can be on the left hand side of an assignment.   Although not technically a function call, it visually looks like one to mere humans.

Comment: @Peter You're right. It's just appearance, after preprocessing the compiler will translate something different.